# How to scroll back to the given line in the Ubuntu xterm and PuTTY line history buffer, or display exactly one screenful of text?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, putty, xterm

I use both PuTTY and xterm bash consoles to access an Ubuntu 12.04. I have a build script that calls `cmake` and pipes STDERR to STDOUT. When there is a compile-time error, the console sometimes fills with pages of error messages. I'm interested in only the first few messages, so have to scroll up multiple times to see it. How can I place some sort of mark (e.g. ANSI escape code) before the cmake command and programmatically scroll the buffer back to that point?

If not possible, how can I truncate the output to exactly one screenful of text, given that the window size is variable? I would normally use the `LINES` environment variable but it's not accessible, as `set` shows. `man pg` talks about "system-supplied number of lines", and `pg` still works, so how can I get this value?

Answer (score 1):

Neither [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) nor [xterm](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.html) has a way for you to mark the scrollback area and cause the terminal to scroll back with that at the top of the screen.  Like many features this would be "doable", but not fall into the normal usage.

The essential part of the question is

> how can I truncate the output to exactly one screenful of text

You *could* do this by (as implied) some type of pager.  `pg` is too limited to consider.  Some text editors could be made to do this—with some work.  Both [vim](http://www.vim.org/) and [vile](http://invisible-island.net/vile/vile.html) can read a file from the standard input; both have scripting languages. Neither (as far as I know) have a pre-made script for doing this:

- reading the input file
- jumping back to the beginning of the first error message
- writing to a file the *visible* part of the screen (the point of the question).

If there were no line-wrapping, the script would be fairly simple, since the operations for `H` (top of screen), `L` (bottom of screen) and copying text in a range from from line to another are part of the original `vi`.

Line-wrapping complicates things.  It is possible to have a line which wraps longer than the screen.  It is certainly possible to have a shorter line which wraps past the end of the visible screen.  A macro could be written to find the end of the screen and save that amount of text.  But there is no built-in feature to simplify it (see for example *[All the right moves](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/All_the_right_moves)*).  It is "doable".

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. I have been considering `more` or `less` too. Is there a way to pipe keystrokes to either, to display just the first page so the user needn't press any keys? I tried `(make 2>&1) | more <<< 'q'` but `more` displays 'q' instead of the first page of `make` output then quitting.

Comment: In your example it seems that you have `more` attempting to read from two different stdin's (and according to your comment the latter only is shown). You *could* use a pager if the data were already in a (temporary) file, but I don't see that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

`$(stty size|cut -d' ' -f1)` answers the second part, but counts logical lines, not screen lines, so doesn't handle lines that wrap around.